TUIC v5 protocol
Wanted to start the TUIC v5 protocol by using these commands to prepare server for the installation:
apt-get update
apt install nano
apt install net-tools
apt install uuid-runtime
apt install wget

then make a directory on server
mkdir tuic
cd tuic

downloading tuic core:
wget -O tuic-server https://github.com/EAimTY/tuic/releases/download/tuic-server-1.0.0/tuic-server-1.0.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu && chmod 755 tuic-server

creating certificate:
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -out ca.key
openssl req -new -x509 -days 36500 -key ca.key -out ca.crt  -subj "/CN=bing.com"

receiving uuid and updating config file according to it
uuidgen
nano config.json

this is my config file:
{
     "server": "[::]:8880",
            "users": {
                "fdf6fa59-7a79-48ea-bab1-0f1dbe7fb6ee": "xxx"
                     },
         "certificate": "/root/tuic/ca.crt",
         "private_key": "/root/tuic/ca.key",
         "congestion_control": "bbr",
         "alpn": ["h3", "spdy/3.1"],
         "udp_relay_ipv6": true,
         "zero_rtt_handshake": false,
         "dual_stack": true,
         "auth_timeout": "3s",
         "task_negotiation_timeout": "3s",
         "max_idle_time": "10s",
         "max_external_packet_size": 1500,
         "send_window": 16777216,
         "receive_window": 8388608,
         "gc_interval": "3s",
         "gc_lifetime": "15s",
         "log_level": "warn"
}

but, when I want to check whether my config is listened to port by this command ./tuic-server -c config.json
I counter with this error :
   No such file or directory (os error 2)

although, when I run ls command the result shows this file along others:
ls
ca.crt  ca.key  config.json  tuic-server

Moreover, GitHub relating to this issue became hidden :
https://github.com/EAimTY/tuic/commits?author=EAimTY

It does not seem to be complaining about the config.json file being missing because the file is already there. It is complaining about some other file missing; however, the error message is not descriptive enough and does not mention the file name which makes it hard to debug.
You can clone the repository and run the file manually, which probably is a Python file, to see where exactly in the code it is looking for a file and what is missing.
